# Laravel Fetch MySQL Results by Relevant Table Column Value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 3 tables. Quizzes, Questions and Answers. Columns I want to use are;

**Quizzes** > *id*

**Questions** > *quizid* (blongs quiz)

**Answers** > *userid, questionid* (belongs question)

So my **Answers** table has no **QuizID** column. What I want is; group **answers** table by ***user ID*** depending on ***Question ID*** that belongs to specified ***Quiz ID***.

In short; I want users that solved the Quiz. But I'm in a dead end :/

My query is like that;

```
Answer::join('questions', 'questions.id', '=', 'answers.id')
->join('quizzes', 'questions.quiz_id', 'quizzes.id')
->join('users', 'users.id', 'answers.userid')
->where('questions.quiz_id', $id)
->select('users.*')
->groupBy('questions.quiz_id')
->get()
```

My mistake is at the **groupBy** line. I don't want to group questions. I want to group answers that belongs to Quiz's questions. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works. Read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for know how to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: seems like you need to learn a couple about query and JOINS. [Laravel Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins) 
| [QUERIES JOINS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: @AndréWalker I tried that but I couldn't achieve. Like that:

Answer::join('questions', 'questions.id', '=', 'answers.id')
->join('quizzes', 'questions.quiz_id', 'quizzes.id')
->join('users', 'users.id', 'answers.userid')->where('questions.quiz_id', $id)->select('users.*')->groupBy('questions.quiz_id')->get()

Comment: what was the errors you received?

Comment: update your question with the attempt and the errors

Comment: It always returns one result. I checked the code again, and found out that it groups by Questions. But I couldn't figure, how can i check every answer that belongs to this Quiz's questions.

Comment: @I.Kaya If you want users then you need to group by user not answer , so that you will have the list of users that solved a particular quiz, also I don;t think you need any details to show for answers added for that quiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get list of users that attempted specific quiz as

```
$users= User::whereHas('answers.question.quiz', function (Builder $query) use ($id) {
                 $query->where('id', $id);
             })->get();
```

Or from joined query as

```
$users = DB::table('users as u')
            ->join('answers as a', 'u.id', '=', 'a.userid')
            ->join('questions q', 'q.id', '=', 'a.questionid')
            ->join('quizzes qz', 'q.quiz_id', 'qz.id')
            ->where('qz.id', $id)
            ->select(['u.id','u.name','q.id as qz_id','qz.name as qz_name'])
            ->groupBy(['u.id','u.name','q.id','qz.name'])
            ->get();
```

Comment: That works perfect! Thank you so much! But I have another question about first code. You used 'answers.question (every column in questions table I guess).quiz (same as before)'. But what if I have different table name than model? (Like in different language). How can I use that line in case of that situation?

Comment: @I.Kaya In first query the navigation properties of models are used these are not table names, like in user model there will be a relationship method which points to related answers for that user, in answer model there will be a relationship method which points to question model and same in question model there will be a relationship method that points to quiz model, check docs [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)